# Python - how to use "open" to create a folder with a dot in the name (without the dot being interpreted as an extension)?

Tags: python, path, operating-system

I am writing a function that will loop over a list of company names and for each create a numbered folder e.g. "1.company_name".

However, at least on a mac, the dot always gets interpreted as a file extension:

from pathlib import Path
for i in range(len(drm_list_of_company_names)): 
current_path = Path(destination_path + "/" + str(i + 1) + "." + drm_list_of_company_names[i])
current_folder = open(current_path,"w")

How to make the loop simply create numbered folders that include a dot in the name, on a mac?

Comment: A folder cant not have a extension, a file can.

Comment: Yes -  I don't want to give the folder an extension. However, I want to create folders with a "." in their names - and these always get interpreted as files with an extension by macbook. How do I keep the dot in the name, but the files being created as folders?